# Login to App Engine using existing Android account

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication

I want implement login with google account in my Android app. with an App Engine backend.
I've found this post explaining the Android side: http://devblog.consileon.pl/2014/01/14/Android-authentication-against-Google-App-Engine/

but I have some questions:

1. Is this method safe or is it deprecated (I initially read this article: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app saying that it uses ClientLogin for installed apps which is deprecated)
2. In the article it's specified that App engine settings should have Google Accounts API activated, but I need to have Federated Login because i have clients that use their yahoo address (and android's AccountManager does not provide an authToken when selecting a yahoo account). Will this method work if i have Federated Login active ? (will it work with google accounts or google apps accounts?)
3. How does the app engine java code looks like ? how do I determine the user ? Do I use

   UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService(); 
   User crtuser = userService.getCurrentUser();
4. How do I make the requests to my server when developing in localhost ? I have tried some manual requests using a token given by my test app in android and it redirects to the local dev servers' login page (the one containing "test@example.com as default user)